# Pulling out sequences of hash values in Perl

Tags: perl, sorting, join, hash

I have two hashes:

1)  %redundant_text has the starting positions of key phrases in a document as the hash keys, with the length of each key phrase as the values.

2)  %itter_w has the sequential number of each word in the document as its keys (1,2,3, and so on), with the corresponding word as each key’s value.

I want to create an array of key phrases from the document by extracting all the values (words) from %itter_w assigned to keys between the starting and ending positions determined by elements of the %redundant_text hash.  The code below does this successfully, but very, very slowly.  Any ideas on how to structure this code to maximize the speed of the output generating process?

```
my @redundant_text ;
my @all_redundant_text ;

foreach my $key (keys %redundant_text) {
    my $start_position = $key  ;
    my $end_position = $key + $redundant_text{$key}+10 ;
    foreach my $word (sort {$a<=>$b} keys %itter_w) {
        next if (($word < $start_position)||($word>$end_position)) ;
        push (@redundant_text, $itter_w{$word})
    }
    ### Blanking out the redundant text array. ###
    my $redundant_sequence = join(' ', @redundant_text) ;
    @redundant_text = () ;
    push (@all_redundant_text, $redundant_sequence) ;
}
```

Comment: I don't *quite* follow what you're trying to do, but the way you're going about it seems awfully convoluted. Can you explain exactly *what* you're trying to do instead of how you're trying to do it?

Comment: not sure if i understand right  but if  `itter_w`  has every word `keyed` on its position shouldn't array be more suited than hash for `itter_w`

Comment: Could you please provide a sensible value for `%redundant_text` and `%itter_w`.

Comment: I want to create an array of key phrases in a document, where "key phrases" are identified based on whether they contain redundant terms found elsewhere in the text.  So I have a hash (%redundant_text) where each element is of the form (x, y), where x is the nth word in the document (the starting point for the redundant phrase to be extracted) and y is essentially the number of words in the redundant phrase. I'm using those two data points to identify the sequence of words in the original document to extract.

Answer (score 3):

This will be much faster. The following are the main changes:

- The list of lengths of sorted once, not once per phrase. [mob's second solution does this as well]
- Only the required number of words are looked up, rather than iterating over all the words. [A better version of mob's first solution]
- The words were copied from the hash into an array for faster lookups.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

# Formerly known as %itter_w.
my %words_by_index = (
   0 => "I",        5 => "array",     10 => "the",          15 => "the",   
   1 => "want",     6 => "of",        11 => "document",     16 => "values",
   2 => "to",       7 => "key",       12 => "by",           17 => "words",
   3 => "create",   8 => "phrases",   13 => "extracting",   18 => "from",
   4 => "an",       9 => "from",      14 => "all",          19 => "itter_w",
);
# Formerly known as %redundant_text.
my %phrase_lengths_by_offset = (2=>3, 10=>4);

# Sort before the loop, and convert to a more-efficient array.
my @words = map { $words_by_index{$_} } sort { $a <=> $b } keys(%words_by_index);

my @phrases;
for my $offset( sort { $a <=> $b } keys(%phrase_lengths_by_offset)) {
   my $length = $phrase_lengths_by_offset{$offset};
   push @phrases, join(' ', @words[$offset .. $offset+$length-1]);
}

say for @phrases;
```

Output:

```
to create an
the document by extracting
```

Comment: This works perfectly!  My code is much faster now.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For one, since `%itter_w` never changes in your loop, you should only need to sort it once, outside the loop instead of in every iteration.

```
my @words = sort {$a<=>$b} keys %itter_w;
foreach my $key (...) {
   ...
   foreach my $word (@words) {
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I see this does help speed up the process!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For another, since `$word` only gets larger as you iterate through `@words`, you should be able to short-circuit your loop. This will save a lot of time when `$end_position` is small but `$word` can get really big:

```
foreach my $word (sort {$a<=>$b} keys %itter_w) {
    next if $word < $start_position;
    last if $word > $end_position;
    push (@redundant_text, $itter_w{$word})
}
```

Comment: Yes, this also helps!  Of course it makes sense to exit the loop once $word is bigger than the end position.  Thank you!